# unable to convert pandas columns from object to float in python

Tags: pandas

I'm making using a panda frame containing columns like below:

```
data = {'chindice': [ '-1', '5.89 e-06', '6.76 e-06', '6.31 e-06', '1',
       '4', np.nan], 
        'target': ['classe1', 'classe2', 'classe3', np.nan,'classe5', 'classe4', 'classe5' ], 
         }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I need to use the columns "chindice" as float, but I couldnt because the columns dtype is 'object'.
Any help would be appreciated. I am a newbie to pandas.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) after stripping the problematic space in your scientific notation entries using [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
In [15]:
df['chindice'] = pd.to_numeric(df['chindice'].str.replace(' ',''), errors='force')
df

Out[15]:
   chindice   target
0 -1.000000  classe1
1  0.000006  classe2
2  0.000007  classe3
3  0.000006      NaN
4  1.000000  classe5
5  4.000000  classe4
6       NaN  classe5
```

Don't worry about the display, the real value is still there:

```
In [17]:
df['chindice'].iloc[1]

Out[17]:
5.8900000000000004e-06
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) arbitrary whitespace `\s+` and then cast by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) to `float`:

```
df['chindice'] = df.chindice.str.replace(r'\s+','').astype(float)
print df
   chindice   target
0 -1.000000  classe1
1  0.000006  classe2
2  0.000007  classe3
3  0.000006      NaN
4  1.000000  classe5
5  4.000000  classe4
6       NaN  classe5

#temporaly display with precision 8
with pd.option_context('display.precision', 8):
    print df
     chindice   target
0 -1.00000000  classe1
1  0.00000589  classe2
2  0.00000676  classe3
3  0.00000631      NaN
4  1.00000000  classe5
5  4.00000000  classe4
6         NaN  classe5
```